# Cannot position properly bootstrap checkboxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style my form with Bootstrap and have got a small problem with checkboxes - they are not positioning properly (I want them to be on the left side).

Can you tell me how can I fix it? 
Should I also add bootstrap styles to the "CheckList" component?

Here is a link to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/leocete/pen/xmrgox?editors=0111)

A source code:

```
// Lists of activities and restrictions
const optionsList = ['Science Lab','Swimming','Cooking','Painting'];
const checkList = [{id: 'a', text:'Dietary Restrictions'},
                   {id: 'b', text:'Physical Disabilities'},
                   {id: 'c', text:'Medical Needs'}]
// First Name and LastName component
function NameInput(props){
  return (
    <div className='form-group'>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <br/>
      <input type ='text' name={props.name} className='form-control' value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
// List of activities componnt
function SelectList(props) {
  return (
    <div className='my-1 mr-2'>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <br/>
      <select className="custom-select mr-sm-2" name={props.name} value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange}>
        {props.optionsList.map( (item, index) =>
            <option key={index} value = {item}> {item} </option>)}
      </select>  
    </div>
  )
}
// CheckBox list component
function CheckBox(props){
   return (
     <p className='form-check'>
       <label className = 'form-check-label'>{props.value}) {props.label}</label>
       <input className = 'form-check-input' type="checkbox" name={props.name} id={props.id} value={props.value} checked={props.checked} onChange={props.handleChange} />
     </p>
   )
}
// CheckbBoxList component
function CheckBoxList(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{props.title}</label>
      <ol>
        {props.checkList.map((item,index) =>
          <CheckBox 
            key = {index}
            id = {props.id+'_'+index}
            name = {props.id}
            value = {item.id}
            checked = {(props.applyList.indexOf(item.id) < 0 ? false : true)}
            label = {item.text}
            handleChange = {props.handleChange}
           />)
         }
      </ol>
    </div>
  )
}
// Remove button component
function RemoveButton(props){
  return (
    <button onClick = {(e)=>{props.removeItem(props.index)}} >x</button>
  )
}
// Report element
function ReportElem(props){
  debugger;
  return (
    <tbody>
    {props.reportList.map((item, index) => 
      <tr key={index}>
        <td><RemoveButton removeItem={props.removeItem} index={index}/></td>
        <td>{item.firstName}</td> 
        <td>{item.lastName}</td>
        <td>{item.activity}</td>
        <td>{item.apply}</td> 
      </tr>
    )}
    </tbody>
  )
}
// Report table
function ReportTable(props){
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Remove</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Activity</th>
          <th>Restrictions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <ReportElem removeItem={props.removeItem} reportList = {props.reportList} />
    </table>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      activity: this.props.optionsList[0],
      apply: [],
      items: []
    }
  }
  // Handle multiple inputs
  handleChange(event){   
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }
  // Handle CheckList changes
  handleChangeChk(event){
    let itemsCopy = this.state.apply
    if (event.target.checked){
      itemsCopy.push(event.target.value)
    } else {
      console.log(itemsCopy.indexOf(event.target.value))
      itemsCopy.splice(itemsCopy.indexOf(event.target.value), 1)
    }
    this.setState({apply: itemsCopy})
  }
  // Add new item to the report and refresh the initial state
  addItem(){
    let itemsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items)) 
    itemsCopy.push({
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      activity: this.state.activity,
      apply: this.state.apply.join(',')
    })
    this.setState({
      firstName: '', 
      lastName: '',
      activity: this.props.optionsList[0],
      apply: [],
      items: itemsCopy
    })
  }

  removeItem(index){
    let itemsCopy = this.state.items.slice()
        itemsCopy.splice(index,1);
        this.setState({items:itemsCopy})
    }


  render(){
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <NameInput label = 'First Name' value = {this.state.firstName} name="firstName" handleChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <NameInput label = 'Last Name' value = {this.state.lastName} name="lastName" handleChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <SelectList label = 'Select Activity' name="activity" optionsList={this.props.optionsList} value = {this.state.activity} handleChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <CheckBoxList title = {'Check all that apply'} name="apply" checkList={this.props.checkList} applyList = {this.state.apply} handleChange = {this.handleChangeChk.bind(this)} />
        <button className = 'submit' onClick = {() => this.addItem()}>Submit</button>
        {this.state.items.length > 0 && <ReportTable removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} reportList = {this.state.items} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App optionsList={optionsList} checkList={checkList}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the input and label from place. See pen for example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BvJXqL?editors=0111#0

`// CheckBox list component
function CheckBox(props){
   return (
     <p className='form-check'>
       <input className = 'form-check-input' type="checkbox" name={props.name} id={props.id} value={props.value} checked={props.checked} onChange={props.handleChange} />
       <label className = 'form-check-label'>{props.value}) {props.label}</label> 
     </p>
   )
}`

You can find an example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios

If you want them more aligned to the left, you should be adding `ol { padding: 0; }` to your `CSS`